# rewriting recursive form to iterative. exception handling

Tags: c#, .net, loops, exception, recursion

Consider such a function:

```
void RequestThings(List<Things> container, Connection connection, Int32 lastVersion) {
    var version = lastVersion;
    try {
        foreach(var thing in connection.RequestThings(version)) {
            container.Add(thing);
            version = thing.lastVersion;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        RequestThings(container, connection, version + 1);
    }
}
```

But this choice is far not perfect: it involves adding to a recursion depth (up to a stack overflow) in case if there are (many) exceptions.

How do I rewrite this the iterative way?

I've tried to do this like:

```
var container = new List<Things>();
var version = getLastVersionFromDB();

foreach(var thing in connection.RequestThings(version)) {
    try {
        container.Add(thing);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

But it appears that `exception` doesn't get handled. How do I do this?

**edit. the details**

1. `Connection.RequestThings(Int32 startVersion)` requests data from a remote server. Accepts a seed version as its only parameter. There might be blocked/damaged documents which you cannot request though they appear on the results returned by calls to `Connection.RequestThings(Int32 startVersion)`. **This piece throws the exception**
2. Don't know why but the inner `try/catch` in my `iterative` example doesn't catch the exception.

Comment: If you add a try catch block withing a for loop it will handle the exception and continue running a loop

Comment: The recursive part of this only seems to happen in the `catch` block, and it isn't clear under what scenarios it might `throw`...? (the `connection.RequestThings(version)` is a different method, and it isn't clear that it calls into this one). Can you clarify?

Comment: I hope this is only a bad example and not actual code. In the real world, you should not catch `Exception` in most cases.

Comment: Shouldn't the version number also be returned from this method?

Comment: this looks like really bad design recursion and `try...catch` aside. why are you relying on errors to find out something's version?

Comment: I have to work with third party code that presents really poor api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's a bad idea to have a `catch` clause for all exceptions. Consider catching only a specific exception type to be sure that you're not swallowing unexpected errors.

Additionally, if you got a stack overflow in the first place, it indicates that you might be doing something wrong. For example, what happens if you pass an invalid `version` number to this method, and there are no documents with a larger version number available? This method will keep running forever, with no chance to gracefully cancel it. Especially since it seems that you are getting the "last version" from a database somehow; if this fails, you can be pretty certain that no higher version exists.

Having said that, you can simplify the method by creating an "infinite" loop and then using `return` to exit the method on success:

```
void RequestThings(List<Things> container, Connection conn, int version)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try 
        {
            foreach (var thing in connection.RequestThings(version))
            {
                container.Add(thing);
                version = thing.lastVersion;
            }

            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {   
            Log.Error(ex);
            version++;
        }
    }
}
```

A slightly better approach might be to make sure that you really get the entire list on success, or nothing. The way your code is written right now leaves the possibility of `container` being filled multiple times if an exception happens while iterating.

```
List<Things> RequestThings(Connection conn, int version)
{
    while (true)
    {
        try 
        {
            // this will either create an entire list,
            // or fail completely
            return connection.RequestThings(version).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {   
            Log.Error(ex);
            version++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really dont like the while(true) and return inside the while... what happens if the connection is down?

Comment: @AK_: The point of the question as I see it is to eliminate recursion which would happen in that case, but I completely agree with you: this method is the wrong place to keep retrying, without any possibility to cancel the operation.

Comment: you answered the question as asked. but the question is bad, and the code example in your answer is bad too... I'm just saying...